# Applying Filter to Core Image is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, video, core-image

I'm using `AVVideoComposition` in order to apply filters to a video. It works fine, but it takes a very long time for the video to be generated. On the other hand, I notice that exporting the video without applying filters is very fast so I know that the process of applying the filter is the issue here.

This is some of the code I'm using to add the filters to the video:

**This code generates the composition for the video.**

```
public func generateComposition() -> AVVideoComposition {
    let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset) {
        request in
        let source = request.sourceImage.clampingToExtent()
        self.zoomBlurFilter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        let currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime)
        let totalTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.asset.duration)
        let timePercentage = currentTime/totalTime
        self.zoomBlurFilter.setValue(timePercentage * Float64(self.blurAmount), forKey: "inputAmount")

        let imageCenter = self.centerOfFirstFace(for: request.sourceImage) ?? CIVector(x: request.sourceImage.extent.midX, y: request.sourceImage.extent.midY)
        self.zoomBlurFilter.setValue(imageCenter, forKey: "inputCenter")

        guard let blurFilterOutput = self.zoomBlurFilter.outputImage else { request.finish(with: self.compositionError); return }

        self.vignetteFilter.setValue(blurFilterOutput, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        guard let vignetteFilterOutput = self.vignetteFilter.outputImage?.cropping(to: request.sourceImage.extent) else { request.finish(with: self.compositionError); return }

        request.finish(with: vignetteFilterOutput, context: self.context)
    }

    return composition
}
```

**This code exports the video to an output file.**

```
public func exportFilteredVideo(to outputURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Void) -> Void) {
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputURL.path) {
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
    }

    let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)!
    export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    export.outputURL = outputURL
    export.videoComposition = generateComposition() // Commenting out this line makes it go very fast, but obviously there is no filter if I comment this line out.
    export.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: completion)
}
```

**Here's the context I'm using:**

```
let context = CIContext(options: [kCIContextCacheIntermediates: false])
```

Are there any steps I should take in order to maximize the speed and performance of the `CIFilters`? The video itself is only three seconds so I see no reason it should be taking this long :(.

Comment: I only work with still images, but my favorite resource has no less than two articles (one with a Github repository) that may help. These were written in Swift 2, but they should be a good start: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2015/07/applying-cifilters-to-live-camera-feed.html?view=magazine http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2016/04/loading-filtering-saving-videos-in-swift.html?view=magazine There's probably more too - a quick site search on "video" had 59 hits.

Comment: @dfd Thanks for the tip :)! I'll check it out right now

Comment: Hey Harish. Did you solved it by chance?

Comment: @RoiMulia I haven't been able to solve it yet :(. I've since moved on.